# Convergence of recursively defined sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Given the two sequences that are defined recursively, I need to prove they are convergent:$$ (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})=(1-\frac {1}{3}y_n^2,\,\, 1-\frac {1}{4}x_n^2), \,\,n\geq0, \,\,(x_0,y_0)=(0,0).$$

I am not quite sure if I understand well the construction of both sequences, i.e. are they dependent of each other.I first thought that one should look at it componentwise, but since this seems to be shifted, I am confused in computing some terms. Anyway, if I did it well, I got the first terms, $(0,0), (1,1), (3/4, 2/3), (55/64, 23/27).$

Can somebody propose a tip or solution proposal ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: consider $(x_{n+2}, y_{n+2})$ as a function of $(x_{n}, y_{n})$.

Comment: *Hint.* The function $$ F(x,y) = \left(1-\frac{1}{3}y^2, 1-\frac{1}{4}x^2\right) $$ defines a map from $[0,1]^2$ to $[0,1]^2$ itself and satisfies $$ \|F(\mathrm{x}_1)-F(\mathrm{x}_2)\|\leq\frac{2}{3}\|\mathrm{x}_1-\mathrm{x}_2\| \qquad\text{for all } \mathrm{x}_1, \mathrm{x}_2 \in [0,1]^2. $$

Comment: Thanks. I do not see, how to use this and how did you get this. It seems to be a Lipschitz continuous function.